# Unable to install git in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: drivers, wireless, git

I'm trying to install the drivers for a wireless adapter on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I had read a few posts where they explain how to do this, but the first step seems to be to install the `git` package, I try to do this with this command: `sudo apt install git`. The command runs but at the end is giving me this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git: Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

Again what I'm trying to do is to get a wireless adapter to work on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.  The driver names is rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4.

I'm new to Linux so any detailed help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add out of `apt-cache policy liberror-perl git` to the question.

Comment: Did you first run: `sudo apt update` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install git
```